# keras val_loss different each time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am a newbie of Keras. I'm working on a deep learning model with a LSTM layer.
**But the val_loss output is quite different each.**
For example，this is my first running output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Epoch 1/40
500/500 [==============================] - 10s 19ms/step - loss: 0.4310 - val_loss: 1.9291
Epoch 2/40
500/500 [==============================] - 8s 16ms/step - loss: 0.2082 - val_loss: 2.1047
Epoch 3/40
500/500 [==============================] - 8s 17ms/step - loss: 0.1810 - val_loss: 2.1206
Epoch 4/40
500/500 [==============================] - 8s 15ms/step - loss: 0.1679 - val_loss: 2.2483
```

[image]

And this is my second running output:

```
Epoch 1/40
500/500 [==============================] - 8s 16ms/step - loss: 0.4424 - val_loss: 0.2251
Epoch 2/40
500/500 [==============================] - 8s 17ms/step - loss: 0.2142 - val_loss: 0.2313
Epoch 3/40
500/500 [==============================] - 8s 16ms/step - loss: 0.1807 - val_loss: 0.2031
Epoch 4/40
500/500 [==============================] - 8s 16ms/step - loss: 0.1682 - val_loss: 0.2667
```

[image]

I don't know why it happened, and I cannot solve overfit problem with it.
Here is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras import regularizers
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(64,
                     kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), 
                     dropout=0.2,
                     recurrent_dropout=0.5,
                     input_shape=(None, float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                              steps_per_epoch=500,
                              epochs=40,
                              validation_data=val_gen,
                              validation_steps=val_steps)
```

My data size is 2733 rows × 50 columns, batch_size is 32.
Thanks for all your help! If needed, I can offer more code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe anything is wrong with the code. It's just a bit of randomness as is expected with any form of machine learning. As long as the loss values are not fluctuating too much, it should be a problem at all. Just think of it as the computer learning the same thing but with different steps.

Cheerio!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I upload two val_loss images, It seems strange for same code.

Answer (score -1):

You are changing the weights while training. Of course the validation loss changes.. and hopefully it goes down and is similar to the training loss, this could mean you are not overfitting!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I upload two val_loss images, is it overfitting?

Comment: How many  data points do you have? How big is a batch? Could you run the experiment longer?